# Can women wear jeans and t shirt at home?

Tags: halal-haram, clothing

Can a woman wear jeans and t shirt at home? Because it is man's clothing.

Answer (score 1):

Women can wear those at home in the presence of Mahrams (Those not permitted to marry). However, if she is with non-Mahrams (those permitted to marry) she must cover herself. The Islamic dress code is divided into two: Public and Private sphere. In the public sphere she must cover everything except for her face and hands (from wrist downwards). In the private sphere she can dress modestly without covering everything as long as she is with mahrams.

Read [this](https://www.islamiqate.com/3815/for-woman-newly-converted-islam-what-dress-code-acceptable) for more detail with evidences

Answer (score -1):

Women can wear jeans or T-shirt in their home in front of their mahrams. Because jeans and shirts is a man clothing and it shouldn't be wore outside so the whole world can see the women. The women should wear those clothes which don't reveal her private parts. It is considered as sin to reveal open arms, open hair and revealing your private parts to non- mahrams. But u can wear whatever u want in front your mahrams e.g Husband, Children, Father, Brother. If a women wants to wear jeans outside then The clothes should be loose fit. The backside should be covered. The arms, legs, chest and hair should also be covered. But u can wear it in your house in front of your mahrams in any style.

Comment: Prophet( SAW)"Has cursed men who make themselves like women and has cursed women who make themselves like men". So is it permissable for a woman to wear jeans and t shirt?

Comment: Wearing jeans for a woman does not imply herself to be like a man. I believe jeans are unisex and there are also specifically for woman too. In addition, jeans are not illegal and is _Mustahabb_ to wear. But it can be haram if it does not follow the standards and limitations that have been determined by the syara' for both men and women. As an example, it is forbidden to wear jeans that are torn on the thighs, calves or parts that are necessary for a Muslim to cover to protect his aurat during outside. Same goes for t-shirt.

Comment: Jazakallah khair